# XUnit and ITestOutputHelper instantiation

Tags: c#, xunit, serilog

I'm trying to use ITestOutputHelper to use Serilog.  While I see that I can inject this as a parameter, I have a base class that handles all the configuration and many tests now that derived from this base class.

I don't want to have to add a constructor to each base class to inject this value, is there a way to manually instantiate this?

I did try var output = new TestOutputHelper(); but it does not seem to work.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to pass it in constructor of your test class, so framework knows which logs belong to which test.